# provide usage notes aimed at the broad astrophysics community

Tags: phrase-usage

It appears to me that the phrase "aimed at the broad astrophysics community" can simply be "for the broad astrophysics community." I am not absolutely sure. It is probably a humorous usage in astrophysics community: Aiming at a galaxy and aiming at a community are all the same for both are parts of the Universe.

But my guess is that the writer is not very good at English. "For" is better than "aimed at". I am not sure.

> We describe the Dark Energy Survey (DES) photometric data set assembled from the first three years of science operations to support DES Year 3 cosmology analyses, and **provide usage notes aimed at the broad astrophysics community**. This Y3 “GOLD” catalog comprises nearly 5000 deg2 of grizY imaging in the south Galactic cap, including nearly 390 million objects, with depth reaching S/N∼10 for extended objects up to i ∼ 23.0.

Source:  [The Dark Energy Survey](https://www.darkenergysurvey.org/des-year-3-cosmology-results-papers/)

Comment: **aimed at** or **intended for** are perfectly idiomatic in this context. There's no need to change it.

Comment: "But my guess is that the writer is not very good at English." - not so.

Comment: I think you are reading too much into this. You could replace it by _for_ but there is no need to unless you are trying to save words.

Comment: Both are acceptable, but I'd use *for* because *aimed at* is a touch too informal when compared to the rest of the text which is academic, dry, and obtuse.

Comment: **Aimed at** isn't meant to be humorous - it does sound a bit incongruous when paired with "the **broad** astrophysics community," but that community is much smaller than the general public, so it can indeed be "aimed at".  I read this statement as saying that the notes will be technical enough that you need to be a professional astrophysicist to understand them, but not so technical that you need to be an expert in this particular subfield.